# Docker-compose links container but Application throws "no route found"

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, docker-compose, spring-rabbit

I have a web application with database and rabbitMQ services. I am using docker-compose to build and run images.

`rabbitmq:
  image : rabbitmq:3-management
  container_name: rabbitmq
  hostname: rabbitmq
  ports:
    - "15672:15672"
  expose:
    - "5672"
    - "4369"
    - "25672"
coredb:
  container_name: coredb
  build: ./mongodb/
core:
  container_name: core
  build: ./core/
  ports:
    - "80:8080"
    - "5683/udp:5683/udp"
    - "5684/udp:5684/udp"
  links:
    - rabbitmq
    - coredb`

After running

> docker-compose up

All the services get started properly. I can ping rabbitmq and codedb from core's shell. In the **SpringBoot** application code, I am using

> CachingConnectionFactory(hostname)

to connect to rabbitMQ. The hostname i am giving is "**rabbitmq**".  In the logs during event publishing, the error I see is "**No route found**". **Core** service can connect to database properly but cannot connect to rabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `docker inspect <container name>` to inspect the config of the "core" service to make sure the link was setup. You can also check the hostname using `docker exec -ti <container name> cat /etc/hosts` (which I think you did already).

If it looks like it's properly linked up, the issue is probably that the core service is trying to connect to it before the rabbitmq service has actually started.

You can have the "core" service retry a few times (with a short delay) to try and setup the conenction.

Comment: I tried restarting the core docker service but the issue still exist. To rule our Spring API issue, I tried adding rabbitMQ docker container IP on host machines /etc/hosts. If I try to connect to rabbitMQ from host machine giving the same hostname, everything works fine.